# VBA macro find first empty cell on next page

Tags: excel, vba

Is it really true that it is impossible to create a macro in Excel that jumps to the first cell of the next page??

Best regards

Comment: Do you mean selecting cell `A1` in the next worksheet?

Comment: @Gareth yes sort of, except that the line on that page is not "1". It more likely "A57" ish.

Comment: Do you mean the next available cell in column A of the next worksheet? Might be good if you post some of your code so we can understand better.

Comment: @Gareth Yes it is exactly that i want. Sorry I was not clearer on the subject

Answer (score 0):

Use `Sheet.Index` to find the index of the current sheet, then use `Range.Find()` to find the last occupied cell in column A of the next sheet:

```
Dim NextSheetIdx As Long
NextSheetIdx = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Index + 1
If NextSheetIdx > ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count Then Exit Sub

Dim InsertRange As Range
Set InsertRange = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(NextSheetIdx).Columns("A") _
        .Find("*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
If Not InsertRange Is Nothing Then
    Set InsertRange = InsertRange.Offset(1)
Else
    Set InsertRange = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(NextSheetIdx).Range("A1")
End If
InsertRange.Value = "ayy"
```